# I am trying to set other parameters from the values fetched in dropdown. But the values are not displayed. How can I display them

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a dropdown field that sets the name and on selecting the name it should also display the other properties like lastName, profession and so on. The name is displaying but the other values are not. How can I display the values.

```
const Val =({firstName, lastName, Profession}) =>{
   const [dropdown,setDropdown] = useState("Cal")
  return(
    
    <form>
      
      <p>Name: {dropdown}</p>
      
      <select  onChange={(e)=>setDropdown(e.target.value)}>
      {Values.map((data,key) =>{
        return(
          <>
          <option key={key}>{data.firstName}</option>
          <p>LastName : {data.lastName}</p>
          <p>Profession: {data.Profession}</p>
          </>
        );
        
      })}
    </select>
    
    </form>
   
  )
}
```

Comment: why are you putting <p> inside <select> tag like that?
and could you please provide the dummy data for rendering the above component?

Comment: export const Values =[
    {
        firstName: "Cal",
        lastName: "Prasad",
        Profession:"Doctor"
    },
     {
       firstName: "Ankit",
        lastName: "Das",
        Profession:"Engineer"
    },
     {
        firstName: "Seni",
        lastName: "Panda",
        Profession:"Prof"
    },
    ];

Comment: the problem is: you are putting <p> inside <select>
if you want to display other values, remove <p> tag and try to embed data inside <option> tag like this: <option key={key}>
                {data.firstName} {data.lastName}
              </option>

Comment: some piece of code for testing: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gagarin-g4yqz?file=/src/App.js:552-643 (wrote in reactjs, but react-native is similar)

Comment: Actually I dont want to display everything in option. I want the option to have only first names and display other variables in text values

Comment: maybe you need to use other way to store your value, just not to put the other tag inside <section> tag except <option> tag.

Comment: Can I use section tag here?

Comment: of course, but if you want to customize a lot of things inside it, you should use <div> tag and style it yourself, because <select> tag is one of the strictest tag for cusomizing...

Comment: <div> tag would not take dropdown. Is there any other way of solving this error

Comment: customize the html css yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Val =({firstName, lastName, Profession}) =>{
let arr=[]
   const [dropdown,setDropdown] = useState("Cal")
  return(
    
    <form>
      
      <p>Name: {dropdown}</p>
      
      <select  onChange={(e)=>setDropdown(e.target.value)}>
      {Values.map((data,key) =>{
       if(dropdown==data.firstName){
arr=data
}
        return(
          <>
          <option key={key}>{data.firstName}</option>
          </>
        );
        
      })}
    </select>
    <dataVal
     lastName : {arr.lastName}
     profession : {arr.profession}/>
    </form>
   
  )
}

const dataVal=(firstName, lastName, Profession)={
   return(
<p>FirstName is : {firstName}</p>
<p>LastName is : {lastName}</p>
<p>Profession is : {Profession}</p>
)
}
```